# What is the better way to switch between portrait and landscape interfaces?

Tags: iphone, ipad, orientation, uiinterfaceorientation

I have two different views (portrait and landscape) for each screen (home, user info, etc).

The difference between portrait and landscape views is enough to have each one into a different view and view controller because it's not only a relocation and resizing of controls.

To perform the switching between the two views I have a container view controller with *landscapeView_* and *portraitView_* properties and into

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
```

I do the switching.

This behavior is inherited from iPhone programming but now, in iPad, is this approach correct or it's another way to do the switching?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm fairly sure that's the best way to do it.

You probably do this, but I would make sure you support all four orientations - they're sticklers for multiple orientations on the iPad.

Another place to make sure everything is kosher is in your Info.plist file - adding some keys like "Initial interface orientation", "Supported interface orientations", and/or "Supported Interface Orientations (iPad)" or "... (iPhone)" can add some clarity, i.e. when you submit.

Comment: Just a side note: they **recommend** all 4 orientations, but you only have to support two (either portrait up/down or landscape left/right) to get approved.

Comment: You're right - what I said was misleading. I just meant that if he does landscape left and portrait only, for example, they're likely to be fussy.

Comment: Thanks Luke. I'll look the Plist properties to control more the behavior.